# elementos um por cima do outro

Tags: html, css

Estou aprendendo a usar algumas tags e não estou conseguindo colocar o botão por cima daquele texto, o objetivo seria ter o titulo e o texto e do lado o botão e aquele textozinho por baixo do alguem poderia me explicar como devo fazer isso? Deixo uma imagem de exemplo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.cookies {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: gray;
  color: black;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
}

.lado {
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}

.lado1 {
  height: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}

.lado2 {
  height: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<aside class="cookies">
  <div class='lado1'>
    <h1>Este site usa cookies</h1>
    <p>O SAPO e os seus parceiros utilizam Cookies para manter informação do visitante, permitindo determinar as suas preferências, auxiliar no preenchimento de formulários, permitir o acesso a áreas privadas do website onde seja necessária autenticação,
      bem como recolher indicadores de performance, origem e horário dos acessos ao website.</p>
  </div>
  <div class='lado'>
    <button type="button" class='lado'>Fechar</button>
  </div>
  <div class='lado2'>
    <p>Mostrar objetivos <br> Ver lista completa de vendedores</p>
  </div>

</aside>
<div class="porcima"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara basicamente basta vc colocar o botão e o texto abaixo dele dentro de um container, tb com `flex`, e configurar como Coluna e alinhar no centro.

O `flex` tem uma propriedade que vc determina se os elementos dentro dele vão estar em `ROW`, fileira, ou em `COLUMN`, colunas, para isso se usa `flex-direction: column;`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Veja o código abaixo, o que eu alterei eu deixei comentado.**

```css
  .cookies {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: gray;
    color: black;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    height: auto;
  }
  
  .lado {
    display: flex;
    height: auto;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  
  .lado1 {
    height: auto;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  
  .lado2 {
    height: auto;
    bottom: 0;
  }

/*novos estilos*/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.direita {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <aside class="cookies">
    <div class='lado1'>
      <h1>Este site usa cookies</h1>
      <p>O SAPO e os seus parceiros utilizam Cookies para manter informação do visitante, permitindo determinar as suas preferências, auxiliar no preenchimento de formulários, permitir o acesso a áreas privadas do website onde seja necessária autenticação,
        bem como recolher indicadores de performance, origem e horário dos acessos ao website.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="direita"> <!-- Div direita como o btn e o texto dentro -->
      <div class='lado'>
        <button type="button" class='lado'>Fechar</button>
      </div>
      <div class='lado2'>
        <p>Mostrar objetivos <br> Ver lista completa de vendedores</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  
  </aside>
  <div class="porcima"></div>
```